# How is the execution state saved at context switch in x86-64 linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, process

Since the TSS does not store the values of the registers in x86-64, how are those saved when the context switch occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general-purpose registers are mostly saved on the stack; see [`PUSH_REGS`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/arch/x86/entry/calling.h#L66) and [`struct pt_regs`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h#L59). To find actual uses, look for `PUSH_AND_CLEAR_REGS` and `POP_REGS`.

The rest of the CPU state is stored in [`thread_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L467).

Linux avoids the TSS as much as possible (early 32-bit x86 versions used it, but that changed a long time ago).